# SSNiper SSN Scanner support

Tags: centos, compiling, rpm

I work for a major university and we have a policy that requires annual scanning of all computers for social security numbers (SSNs). I started using a utility called [SSNiper](https://wiki.engr.illinois.edu/display/tsg/SSNiper+SSN+Scanner) that was created at UIUC.  Unfortunately, the person who supported the utility is no longer with that university and it seems to have been abandoned.

Anyway, my actual problem is this: I am attempting to compile and build a new RPM for SSNiper for our CentOS 6.2 servers, and while the compile phase seems to work just fine, the "make rpm" portion is dying with an error.

```
rm -f magic_test.o dbase.o ssniper.o list.o validate.o scan_file.o config_file.o ssn_fsm.o extension_test.o logging.o get_line.o list_test.o  ssniper
darcs get . ssniper-`cat VERSION`-`cat RELEASE`
darcs failed:  Not a repository: /home/racooper/download/ssniper-0.9.7-2 (/home/racooper/download/ssniper-0.9.7-2/_darcs/inventory: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory))
make: *** [tarball] Error 2
```

If anyone either has experience with SSNiper, or can suggest solutions to my problem above, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: It seems the `make rpm` is not intended to be run from the tarball but the source repository. Either adjust the `Makefile`, create a darcs repository, or build it on your own - http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package

Answer (score 3):

[Darcs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcs) is a revision control system, less well-known than CVS, Subversion, Git, Mercurial or Bazaar. The `tarball` target in the makefile builds a source archive by pulling files from the repository and generates a changelog from the Darcs history.

If you're using the existing sources, create a tarball with the required name (`ssniper-0.9.7-2.tar.gz`) and create an empty file called `tarball` (use the command `touch tarball`) to prevent the commands for the `tarball` target from running.

If you've modified the sources, edit the `tarball` target in `Makefile.in`: replace the invocation of darcs by what it takes for you to get a clean source archive (`git archive`, `hg archive`, or whatever your revision control system provides). Run `./configure` again to regenerate `Makefile` when you've modified `Makefile.in`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment from Ulrich Dangel, I was able to figure out that I could remove all the calls from rpm to tarball completely, then get it to compile. I also figured out that there were other errors in the makefile and in the .spec file (such as what appear to be duplicate lines, and assuming a 32-bit platform).

Thanks to Gilles too for providing me a little education into darcs and parsing a makefile.